# A noun meaning the 'elision' of whole words rather than sounds [ellipsis]

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Elision refers to dropping sounds or syllables from words.

What is a similar term (noun) for dropping words from a phrase?

**Example**

*I will give you a period of time lasting from now until 10 February to complete this task.*

*I will give you until 10 February to complete this task.*

Because of idiom and familiarity we can drop the direct object of "to give", which would have been "a period of time" - it's understood.

Comment: Implied meaning: 
 
something that was hinted at or suggested, but not directly stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word you might be thinking of is **[ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics))**.

Removing parts of the (subordinate) *adverb clause of time* "a period of time lasting from now until 10 February..." seems like a good example of an **elliptical adverb clause** which is just an adverb clause (one that answers a "where", "when", "how", etc. question) with one or more words removed that can be inferred by context.